# Rails view specs: referenced partials of inherited controllers aren't found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, view, rspec, controller

I have the following controllers:

```
ReportsController # Abstract
ReportTemplatesController < ReportsController
ReportDocumentsController < ReportsController
```

Thus I have the following view folders:

```
app/views/reports # Shared templates
app/views/report_templates
app/views/report_documents
```

For example, in both `.../report_templates/index.html.slim` and `.../report_documents/index.html.slim`, I have this call:

```
== render 'reports', reports: @reports
```

The `_reports.html.slim` partial lives in `.../reports`, as it is used by both of them. This works perfectly.

In the `_reports.html.slim` partial, I do some truncation:

```
= truncate report.description, length: 100
```

I want to assert this using a view spec, as it is cheaper than a feature spec.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "report_templates/index", type: :view do
  it 'Truncates the description' do
    assign :reports, [create(:report_template, description: 'This is a very long description. This is a very long description. This is a very long description. This is a very long description. This is a very long description.')]
    render

    expect(rendered).to have_css '.description', text: 'This is a very long description. This is a very long description. This is a very long description...'
  end
end
```

Sadly, this gives the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) reports/index Truncates the description
     Failure/Error: render

     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template reports/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :axlsx, :jbuilder, :haml]}. Searched in:
         * "/Users/josh/Documents/Work/Access4All/Projects/a4aa2/src/app/views"
```

But when I change the line

```
RSpec.describe "reports/index", type: :view do
```

to e.g.

```
RSpec.describe "reports_templates/index", type: :view do
```

the error changes to:

```
Failures:

  1) report_templates/index Truncates the description
     Failure/Error: == render 'reports', reports: @reports

     ActionView::Template::Error:
       Missing partial /_reports, report_templates/_reports with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :axlsx, :jbuilder, :haml]}. Searched in:
         * "/Users/josh/Documents/Work/Access4All/Projects/a4aa2/src/app/views"
```

So now the references partial, which lives in `reports`, isn't found anymore.

So regardless what view path I provide, the spec doesn't seem to know about controller inheritance and look in the inherited paths itself.

How can I make this spec work?

Answer (score 3):

I found some more information about the issue here:

- [RSpec-Rails issue #396: 'application' view directory not in render path?](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/396#issuecomment-3135336)
- [Rails issue #5213: Missing partial in view specs with template inheritance](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5213)

I found sort of a temporary solution to the problem through these links:

- [Raygun-Rails-Template pull request #14: Update rspec to work with view inheritance.](https://github.com/spartansystems/raygun-rails-template/pull/14)

Just add the inherited folder to the lookup paths manually:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:example, type: :view) do
    view.lookup_context.prefixes << 'reports'
  end
end

RSpec.describe "report_templates/index", type: :view do
  # ...
```

This feels clumsy though. Isn't there a way to do this automatically?

I'm also not sure whether this adds the path to each view spec (which it shouldn't) or only this one (which it should).

**Update**

It seems when I add the view folder to the render call, it works without the workaround above:

```
== render 'reports/reports', reports: @reports
```

instead of only

```
== render 'reports', reports: @reports
```

Still this feels not DRY to me.

**Update**

You better do the change of lookup context for individual specs, otherwise you can mess up other view specs (as I was afraid above), as you change the lookup context for each spec when doing it with `RSpec.configure`.

Just add this to the specific view specs:

```
before do
  view.lookup_context.prefixes << 'reports'
end
```